# Projection on multiple criteria find query

Tags: mongodb

I would like to query documents based on several criteria and then keep only specific fields. The following query (mongoskin syntax) returns todos for the current user, and filtered by tag:

```
db.collection('users').find({
    _id : db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.user._id.toString())
}, {
    todos : {
        $elemMatch : {
            tags : filterTag
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to add the projection but the filtering is not done anymore.

```
db.collection('users').find({
    _id : db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.user._id.toString()),
    todos : {
        $elemMatch : {
            tags : filterTag
        }
    }
}, {
    _id : 0,
    'todos.value' : 1,
    'todos._id' : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution with aggregate:

```
db.collection('users').aggregate({
    $unwind : '$todos'
}, {
    $match : {
        _id : db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.user._id.toString()),
        'todos.tags' : filterTag
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        'todos.value' : 1,
        'todos._id' : 1
    }
}
```